# Google Data Studio: calculated fields VS custom SQL query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a custom SQL query from Google BigQuery as data source in Google Data Studio.
I'm trying to figure out which method has better performance.
Should I use calculated fields or is better to calculate it in my custom SQL query?

Comment: My expectation is that they will be about the same... Why not try it and see, though?

Comment: It's not so easy to test. There is no timer and I should test it on a huge dataset to see which one is the best.

Comment: I'm tempted to say that a specific big data engine is more likely to be performant than the generalist (and pretty new) Google Data Studio ... not to mention being far more flexible in terms of the calculations you can do. Others may disagree but I'd see this as a no-brainer.

Comment: nice point of view